# How to calculate age between Current date - another/selected date in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

Here, I'm implementing Two input fields, first one is selected date & another field will show the days of age/ calculated result.

[image]

I'm getting this error in dev tool:

> The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
> Warning: Received NaN for the `defaultValue` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.

How can I fix it?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Container,Form,Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Calculation = () => {

   const [stockingDate, setStockingDate] = useState(new Date().getTime());

    const current = new Date();
    const date = `${current.getDate()}/${current.getMonth()+1}/${current.getFullYear()}`;
    console.log({date});
    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    const changeHandler = (e)=>{
        setStockingDate(e.target.value);
    }
        useEffect(()=>{
        let newAge = (date - stockingDate)
        setAge(newAge)
    },[date,stockingDate])

    
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Form>
                        <Row className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formStockingDate">
                        <Form.Control type="date" placeholder="Stocking Date" onChange={changeHandler}/>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formAge">
                        <Form.Control type = "number"placeholder = "Age"
                        value = {age}/>
                        </Form.Group>                        
                    </Row>
                    </Form>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Calculation;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a state variable and settings it onChange for the select date field and then calculating the age and setting another state variable(which contains calculated age) as value for the age field?

Comment: Please update question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help fix code we can't see. Please include details about any error messages or about what isn' working as expected, what debugging steps have been taken, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAge(dateString) 
{
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
    {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```